# What is this spoon?

Tags: equipment

I have this weird spoon? I came across in a set of silverware from goodwill, it is shaped like a sidewise smashed heart, or maybe a lung? I tried reverse image searching it, but, couldn't come up with any results

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice. Pro tip: get the spoon on a clean surface and put a ruler next to it. *Then* take a picture.

Comment: Playing a game of "looks like" this appears somewhat like a mini ladle that could be used for condiments or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a butter spade. They come in so many forms, anything heart-shaped and mounted sideways is a butter spade.

Butter spades have a triangular or heart shaped blade usually connected to a round, turned ivory or wooden handle, although completely silver examples are found. They are very collectable and generally date from the mid-late 18th Century. Examples from late Victorian and Edwardian times are found, often attractively engraved with mother of pearl handles.

this is one of those completely silver examples by the looks, I personally cant speak to the value of spoons, but there are dozens of collector websites that will be willing to value it.

Comment: All the butter spades I can find seem to be, well, spade-shaped. One can easily imagine using them to spread butter. The OP's object, on the other hand, looks singularly unsuited to any purpose involving butter.